# Modifying a node module for import usage

Tags: javascript, npm, node-modules

I have a file with some functions which I have basically added to a node module structure...

So I created the following files and then added the folder named 'code' where my file lives.

```
- package.json
- README.md
- LICENSE.md
- code 
    |_______ code.js
```

At the moment if I want to use it I basically do this:

```
  - index.html

  <script src="_node_modules/myexamplemodule/code/code.js"></script>
```

This works but what I would like to do is to be able to use it by doing something like this (for example):

```
import myexamplemodule from 'myexamplemodule';
```

How do I modify my example module so I am able to do this?

ps: I just want to add that code.js is not a module, it's just a few functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might not be referencing the same name as the one in the package.json.

If you are importing `myexampleapp` the name in the package.json needs to be the same. You also need to specify the correct entry point in the package.json.

Take a look at the documentation for more info: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#name

Comment: My problem is that there's no actual module for example: export mymodule... etc I just have a code.js file which contains functions ... not as modules, so no export. Can I still import this? ... trying: import mycode from 'module-name/code/code.js'; but it's not working

Comment: @KevinPorche If you are to use the functions outside of the file you need to export them.